# Feathers - Authentication and Authorization

Tags: authentication, express, authorization, feathersjs

I have created an app using [Feathers](http://feathersjs.com/). I've been using this app for a while. It successfully hosts a blog and some other web pages. However, I've now reached a point where I need to protect some of my routes. For example, I want to have a route for my administrative activitivies (/admin), but I only want specific users to have access.

I know that I need to use the [authentication](https://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/readme.html) and authorization components. However, at this time, I'm stuck on the authorization. My goal is to authenticate using OAuth via Google. However, to get past my authentication challenge, I'd be happy with just using a hard-coded username / password just to get the `/admin` route locked down (no, it's not deployed).

At the moment, I have

```
const app = feathers();
const routes = require('./routes');

app.configure(configuration(path.join(__dirname, '..')));

app.use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  .use(favicon( path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico') ))
  .use('/public', serveStatic(app.get('public'), staticFileSettings ))
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(routes)    
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(socketio())
  .configure(services)
  .configure(middleware)
  .configure(authentication())
;

// Setup the authentication strategy.
app.authenticate({
  type: 'local',
  'email': 'admin@feathersjs.com',
  'password': 'admin'
}).then(function(result){
  console.log('Authenticated!', result);
}).catch(function(error){
  console.error('Error authenticating!', error);
});
```

My problem is, as soon as I add the block of code with the app.authenticate stuff, I get an error when I start my app. The error says:

```
TypeError: app.authenticate is not a function
```

If I remove `app.authenticate(...);` My app starts fine, but nothing is locked down. In my ./routes/index.js file, I have:

```
app.use('/admin', function(req, res) {
    res.render('admin/index.html', {});
});
```

Which, renders just fine. It's just not restricted to an authenticated and authorized user. What am I missing? At a bare minimize I'm trying to understand how to get past the `app.authenticate` error.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `app.authenticate` is only available on the client (`feathers-authentication/client`).

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to prevent unauthorized users from accessing the view on the route `/admin`. From my understanding, there are two things I need to do: 1) authenticate the user (I want to do so via Google's OAuth login) and 2) authorize the user. The question above explains how I'm stuck on #1.

Answer (score 0):

In order to protect a route from unauthorized access you need to [follow the documented usage of express middleware](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication#express-middleware) provided by the `feathers-authentication` package that is installed when you do `feathers generate authentication`.

Here's an example of authenticating the `/admin` route.

```
const auth = require('feathers-authentication');

app.use(
  '/admin',
  auth.express.authenticate('jwt'), // <-- this is a strategy, can local/jwt... etc
  (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Request for '/admin'...");
    res.render('admin');
  }
);
```